# Lubuntu 17.10 resolution problem

Tags: lubuntu, display-resolution, gpu-driver

Recently I installed lubuntu 17.10 on my old HP mini 2140 because it says it is designed for old systems, and so far is going great! But I encountered a few problems after the installation. Even though after I finished installing Lubuntu i rebooted my machine and on start up i had a black screen on the top left corner, that covered 2/3 of the screen.

After reading some other posts about solution I managed to boot the system in "nomodeset" mode and it worked fine, but the resolution was pretty bad. I made it so it boots up that way everytime, and now I don't have to worry about the black box, but the resolution is really bad and when I try to do something it is very blurry.

I tried installing drivers for my integrated intel video card (intel GMA 950) and I think I did something, but I still do not have the option the increase the resolution. I also tried adding new resolution (1024 x 576, which is the maximum for my laptop) using `cvt 1024 576` and then `xrendr` to add it as a mode, and I make it available.

But when I type `xrandr -s 1024x576` it says it cannot change it, and also once I reboot the machine the whole thing is gone, so only the 640x480 is available. I'm pretty new with linux, so I would really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thank you very much,
- turb0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys so I actually found a solution to my own problem :D

I updated the version of my Kernel to the newest available one that is on the Ubuntu website, then restarted the laptop and removed the `nomodeset` command. After that I booted my laptop and it recognized all the possible resolution there are. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue that I had.

- turb0